# MySql query for min and max with grouping

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

Input Table  :

[image: Table]

By considering the above table I want to **list the start and end date grouped by order id** for the given **input status "b"**. Right now I am doing it with many sql queries and merging them together in java. But I would like to write it in single sql query in mysql. Can anyone help me to write this in single sql query.

Output :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
SELECT OrderId, MIN(createdDate) as MinDate, MAX(createdDate) as MaxDate
FROM tbl1
WHERE fromStatus = 'b' or inputStatus = 'b'
GROUP BY OrderId
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you lack the `WHERE` clause in your query.

```
SELECT  orderID, 
        MIN(createdDate) min_date,
        MAX(createdDate) max_date
FROM    tableName
WHERE   'b' IN (fromStatus, toStatus)
GROUP   BY OrderID
```